# In the Evernote iPad app, when you hit the menu button, is that a page sheet that is presented?

Tags: ios, ipad, evernote

For further context, when you are in the Evernote app on the iPad, there is a button of an elephant on the top-left corner that summons a menu once it's pressed.

I'm just curious if that is a page sheet or something different altogether.

I know that when you create a new note from that menu, such as a text note, a page sheet is most definitely presented; hope that provides further context.

[Video of Evernote app demonstration](http://youtu.be/JSFDWX1Qb9g?t=5m46s)

Comment: Update your question with a relevant portion of a screenshot. Not everyone uses Evernote or Evernote could change.

Comment: I've provided a link to a video that demonstrates what I asked, skipped to the relevant sequence for everyone's convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a page sheet

When you tap on the elephant icon, we present a blurred UIImageView on top of your notes(since UIBlurEffect is iOS 8 only and we introduced this since iOS 7), and then add the left sidebar(the menu you're talking about) slide in animation from left. The left sidebar is just a customized UIViewController with a width of 320.

Disclosure: I'm an software engineer on Evernote's iOS team.